# How to do a special operation for the first element in a loop with jinja grammar?

Tags: jinja2

I'm trying to convert the following python code into a jinja template, so that I can use my own chat tempolate in llama tokenizer. But I'm new to this field and don't know what to do.

My python code looks like this:

```
for i in range(len(messages)):
    if i == 0:
        do_something()
    else:
        do_other_things()
```

I tried marking the first element with a variable, the value of which should be changed inside the loop. But in practice the variable stays constant, so my idea didin't work.

The chat template I actually tried:

```
{% set is_first = "false" %}
{% for message in messages %}
    {% if message['role'] == 'system' %}
        {{ '<<SYS>>\\n' + message['content'].strip() + '\\n<</SYS>>\\n\\n'}}
        {% set is_first = "true" %}
    {% elif message['role'] == 'user' and is_first == "true" %}
        {% set is_first = "false" %}
        {{ message['content'].strip() + ' [/INST]' }}
    {% elif message['role'] == 'user' %}
        {{ '[INST] ' + message['content'].strip() + ' [/INST]' }}
    {% elif message['role'] == 'assistant' %}
        {{ message['content'].strip() }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}"""
```

Is there a solution to make my code work? By the way, is there any method to tell jinja raise an error when the order of dialog isn't in "system -> user -> assistant -> user -> ..." fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035728/flask-cannot-import-enumerate-undefinederror-enumerate-is-undefined#:%7E:text=%3E%3E%3E%20from%20jinja2%20import%20Template%0A%0A%3E%3E%3E%20t1%20%3D%20%22%22%22%0A...%20%7B%25%20for%20val%20in%20%5B%27a%27%2C%20%27b%27%2C%20%27c%27%5D%20%25%7D%0A...%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%0A...%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%20loop.index0%20%7D%7D%20%7B%7B%20val%20%7D%7D%0A...%20%20%20%20%20%3C/td%3E%0A...%20%7B%25%20endfor%20%25%7D%0A...%20%22%22%22%0A%3E%3E%3E%20Template(t1).render()). Use `loop.index0` to access the index number in the loop.